# Displaying Firebase Username in Android Studio when logged on?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The XML front-end is a simple textview with a default name of like John Smith. How can you change it to display the username each time you're logged in?

The back-end is where it gets confusing to me, where do I put the Firebase info in the Java activity?

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public Context createDisplayContext(Display display) {
        return super.createDisplayContext(display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd typically put the code to do that in `onStart`, which runs every time the activity starts. There you can either get the currently signed user with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), or use an `AuthStateListener`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // TODO: set user.getDisplayName() to view here
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Which folder? The main.activity?

Comment: This should be in the activity that you want to display the user's name in.